# How to read array of integers from the standard input in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, bufferedreader

in one line from the standard input I have 3 types of integers: the first integer is id, the second integer is N - some number, and after that follows N integers, separeted by a single space which I want to store in array or ArrayList. How can I do this using BufferedReader? I have the following code:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String[] line = br.readLine().split(" ");
int ID = Integer.parseInt(line[0]);
int N = Integer.parseInt(line[1]);
```

My question is is there any elegant way to read the rest of the line and to store it into array?

Comment: How are those following N integers separated?

Comment: the following N integers are separated just by a single space " "

Comment: Using `split` with a restrictive pattern (exactly one space) requires a very accurately prepared input. If you remain with this approach, splitting on a sequence of white space is recommended (`"\\s+"`).

Answer (score 5):

Use `Scanner` and method `hasNextInt()`

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

while (scanner.hasNext()) {

     if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
        arr[i]=scanner.nextInt();
        i++;
     }
  }
```

Comment: This is a general method I've posted. The OP hasn't mentioned his problem specifically. And what's the problem in reading till end of the file if the file contains all integers @laune

Comment: OP has explicitly requested how to read "N - some number, and after that follows N integer" and how to store them into an array or list. His "one line from standard input" is not his *only* line.

Answer (score 4):

> How can I do this using BufferedReader?

You've already read/split the line, so you can just loop over the rest of the inputted integers and add them to an array:

```
int[] array = new int[N];  // rest of the input

assert line.length + 2 == N;  // or some other equivalent check

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    array[i] = Integer.parseInt(line[i + 2]);
```

This will also let you handle errors within the loop (I'll leave that part to you, should you find it necessary).

Comment: A check whether there are enough elements in `String[] line` is recommended.

Comment: @laune Sure, I incorporated that into the answer.